# Returning value from Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have defined a message function to put different messages in it. That means when I call this function in a form, then just the corresponding chosen message has to display on the screen. Here my example:

```
'Thats the message sub
Public Sub MsgString(txtNo As Byte)
    MsgBox MsgTxt(txtNo)
End Sub

'Thats the message function to return the corresponding value, which is chosen
 Private Function MsgTxt(txtNo As Byte) As String
     Dim arrMsgTxt() As Variant
     arrMsgTxt = Array("error message number one", "error message number two", "error message number three")

     For txtNo = LBound(arrMsgTxt) To UBound(arrMsgTxt)
            MsgTxt = arrMsgTxt(txtNo)
            Exit Function
     Next txtNo
 End Function
```

Is there a better way to solve it? Currently, I need to exit the function after the instantiated value.

Comment: Why would you need to loop through the array of error messages if you know (presumably by the value of txtNo) which one of the messages you want to use? You could drop the For and Next lines, along with the Exit Function and have no change to the functionality

Comment: @Dave Yes, the variable `txtNo` contains the number in the array. Do you have an idea for a better solution?

Comment: See Gary's Student's answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to to pass an **index** to the UDF.  That way, you don't need a loop:

```
Public Function TellMe(indx as Long) as String
    ary = Array("Mike", "James", "Paul", "William")
    TellMe = ary(indx)
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    MsgBox TellMe(2)
End Sub
```

*Remember, the default indexing is zero-based............so expect "Paul"*

Comment: Thanks. I had this defined before and had a strange error message, however, now it works :)

Comment: @yuro  Thank you for the feedback!